# Network interface isn't showing in iptables

Tags: iptables, network-interface

When I'm trying to specifying an network interface with this command:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d  217.00.000.0 -j ACCEPT -o enp0s3
```

Why can't I see it here with **iptables -L** command?

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             217.000.000.0
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Sure my friend

If you enter:

```
Iptables -L -v
```

Then it will list a verbose list with more information, there you (I) can see what network interface every rule affects..

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like `iptables-save -c` the best because it is in the same format as you entered it originally. The `-c` adds the counters in front so you can see how many times the rule matched. Useful when diagnosing issues.

Comment: Interesting. I have however evolved(Level +2 ) so I'm using iptables-save > /tmp/iptables.txt and edit everything in a text editor, then just iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables.txt to save it down to the tables. Must not forget the iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 to make it persistent